# Communication between App server and DB server in Java EE

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee

What protocol is used for communication between App server and DB server in Java EE if they are both hosted on different machines?

I mean if I use JDBC, then can I just specify IP of DB server in the config file(connection string)
and the connection will be established?

And if it does get established then what protocol is used to communicate across the two servers?
Is this protocol database dependent?

Or should I have web services on the DB server to communicate with the App server?

Comment: RDBS's are typically free to implement their own protocol.  This is exemplified in the connection URL's that are supplied to JDBC drivers to establish a connection.  For example, for HSQLDB, the URL is: 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://host[:port][/<alias>][<key-value-pairs>]'.  The protocol indicated here is the proprietary 'hsql' protocol.  As JB has indicated, luckily the JDBC driver takes care of communications for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol to communicate with the DB is database dependant. The JDBC driver takes care of communicating with the DB for you.

The URL of the database is also database dependant, and contains the information necessary for the driver to connect to the database server.

Using web services on the DB server is definitely a bad idea:

- it would forbid the use of transactions in the Java EE application
- you wouldn't be able to scroll to results without loading them all in memory
- it would be horribly slow
- the web service on the DB server would still communicate with the same native protocol with the database server.

Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) for more information.

Comment: Nice reasons for not having web services on the DB server...can you elaborate more on "you wouldn't be able to scroll to results without loading them all in memory"?

Comment: Because the Web service would have to return a complete list to the Java app, instead of the Java app iterating directly through a JDBC result set.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the connection is implemented in the JDBC driver. The driver allows to work with some specific DB server. There are propriaetary drivers (like for Oracle for example) or open-source ones.

What to specify usually depends on the DB you work with and how its configured.
You say "just IP", how about user/password, schema (if it exists), port, etc. This stuff is best to be found by Google I believe :)

Regarding the Protocol, usually its custom protocol implemented again in driver. From the point of view of application developer it should be ok as long as the driver implements the specific version of JDBC.

Regarding Web Services, I don't see why should you use them...

Hope, this helps